# What is the best way to create "recursive template"?

Tags: template, render

How could one make a template that based on some condition renders itself again?

Comment: Create an event when the view gets rendered and use an observer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just re-call the `toHtml()` function. Make sure to perform your logic for whatever will stop the recursion before calling `toHtml()`.

```
<?php if (!$this->getStopRecursive()):
    $this->setStopRecursive(true);
    echo $this->toHtml();
endif;?>
```

---

### Update:

You can change the template on the fly:

#### Layout XML

```
<block type="Vendor_Module/Template" 
     template="Vendor/Module/Template.phtml"
     name="template.test">
     <action method="setAltTemplate"><altTemplate>Vendor/Module/Template1.phtml</altTemplate></action>
</block>
```

#### Template/View Code

```
if ($this->getAltTemplate()):
    $this->setTemplate($this->getAltTemplate());
endif;
```

Comment: Would it be possible to set some data to new template?

Comment: See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Magento does this by abandoning the template approach and instead concatenating HTML in a block. You can see this in **/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Topmenu.php**:

```
protected function _getHtml(Varien_Data_Tree_Node $menuTree, $childrenWrapClass)
{
     //...snip
        if ($child->hasChildren()) {
            if (!empty($childrenWrapClass)) {
                $html .= '<div class="' . $childrenWrapClass . '">';
            }
            $html .= '<ul class="level' . $childLevel . '">';
            $html .= $this->_getHtml($child, $childrenWrapClass);
    //...snip

}
```

I recommend not handling it in the block, though. So you could easily create a function in the view and call it:

```
<?php $i = 0; ?>
<?php function recurse($i) { ?>
   <div class="menu-<?php echo $i++; ?>">
       <?php if($i<4) recurse($condition, $i); ?>
   </div>
<?php
 }
recurse($i);
?>
```

Which outputs markup as you'd expect:

```
   <div class="menu-0">
          <div class="menu-1">
          <div class="menu-2">
          <div class="menu-3">
          </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: So you suggest making a function inside a template?

Comment: Yes - if the goal is to call it recursively. If you really hate the idea of a named function you could make this into a Block method, but you'd be back to concatenating HTML in your block which is difficult to manage at best.

Comment: Seems like a lesser of two evils situation :)

Comment: lol a downvote! O NOES A WORKING SOLUTION I DON'T LIKE BECAUSE OF MY POLITICAL POSITION ON NAMED-FUNCTION DEFINITIONS!